# Query String condition in regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to redirect a user who gets from

```
page.php?letter=A&num=2
```

to the following address:

```
 /static/A/2
```

I tried using the following regex:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^letter=([a-zA-Z]+$)&num=([0-9]+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page.php static/%1/%2? [NC,R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work... It seems to me like the first expression `([a-zA-Z]+$)` "catches" the &num=... as well in the URL and that is why it messes up the condition :/

Any ideas how to correct this condition?

Thanks!

Joel

Comment: Does `^letter=([a-zA-Z]+)&num=([0-9]+)$` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably remove the `$` at the end of the parentheses, as it usually means "match the end of line" in regular expressions.

So your `RewriteCond` would be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^letter=([a-zA-Z]+)&num=([0-9]+) [NC]
```

Comment: Maybe with a dollar character at the end?

Comment: I'll add the dollar char at the end. One last problem, it only rewrites when I use one digit number (from 0 to 9). How can I accept all numbers?

Comment: @thejh, it should work anyway, but the dollar may be added. @Joel, it should accept all strings containing only digits, including 12, 123, 1234, 99999, etc. The `+` after `[0-9]` means "one or more", so it should match all numbers.